# Asp.net Login - Working with user data

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

I'm making a simple page and i need a login interface for users.
I want users to login to the page and when he is logged in he gets alot of data from the database that is signed to him alone. I did this before using very simple datatable holding the username, crypted password and the uid. When the user logged in the site i set the uid into a session so i could use it when i was selecting from the database..
This is probably not a safe way....easy to crack ?

Better way would be using the asp.net login id...?

What is the best way to do this, should i have all the user info in the ASPNETDB.MDF, and does that database work when i deploy the site on a server ?

Can i use ASP.NET Configuration when i have deployed ?

[Edit]

How can i use the asp.net login to get the userid of the current logged user so i can do sql querys for him ?

Answer (score 3):

I think you should read more on "ASP.NET authentication" - regarding how to implement user login/logout/get userid etc. And on "ASP.NET authorization" - regarding security and access and come back with certain questions. There's standard mechanism for this.

Start with MSDN:

```
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eeyk640h.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wce3kxhd.aspx
```

Comment: Indeed, this is a topic that you should dedicate some time and effort to learning holistically.

Answer (score 1):

The ASP.NET membership provider will likely be your best approach as it handles all of the basic plumbing which you need. The tables are quick to setup with the ASP.NET SQL Server Setup Wizard (C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Aspnet_regsql.exe) and the combination of the Configuration pages and out of the box login controls will get you up and running quickly. I would recommend going down this path.

Regarding one of your specific questions, the logged in user's Id is stored in the ProviderUserKey. This is the value which maps to the UserId in the membership tables like aspnet_Users and others.  Here's how you get the value:

```
using System.Web.Security;

//ProviderUserKey is an object. 
//You will likely want to convert to string or Guid
MembershipUser user = Membership.GetUser();
Object userId = user.ProviderUserKey;
```

Answer (score 0):

There really is nothing wrong with the way you are doing it, although there are easier methods to do it.

If you are creating a login hash, and storing it in session, the users have no access to that data.

When you create a session state, all that gets sent down in a cookie is a GUID that refers to their own session, and not any of the actual data. Because of this, you can generally assume the data is protected and users can't get access to anyone else's data.